# jquery change active class fixed div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parent-child

I'm new to using JQuery and Javascript. I can't figure out what is wrong here.

I want to h1 element to be displayed as block and to add the class as active as is parent div is showing in the window.

I'm hoping the consequent effect will be somewhat like the 'Y logo' on this site http://www.collectif-yay.com/en

HTML

```
<div class= "section" id="Title">
        <h1 style="position: fixed; top: 10px; display: none">Title</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="Publications">
        <h1 style="position: fixed; top: 10px; display: none">Publications</h1>
    </div>


    <div class= "section" id="Articles">
        <h1 style="position: fixed; top: 10px; display: none">Articles</h1>
    </div>


    <div class= "section" id="Contributors">
        <h1 style="position: fixed; top: 10px; display: none">Contributors</h1>
    </div>


    <div class= "section" id="Process">
        <h1 style="position: fixed; top: 10px; display: none">Process</h1>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    div{
        height: 400px;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    h1 {
        top: 10px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        width: 100%;
        color: #0000aa;
    }


    .section {
      padding-top: 100px;
      padding-bottom: 0px; 
    }

    .active {
      color: #0000aa;
```

JQuery

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
      setup_section_titles();
      display_section_titles();

    });


    $(window).scroll(function () { 
      display_section_titles();
    });


    function setup_section_titles() {
      $("h1").css("position", "fixed").css("top", "10px");
    }


    // ----------------------------------------
    function display_section_titles() {
      var sectionArray = $.makeArray($(".section"));

      var window_scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();
      var window_center = $(window).height()/2;
      window_center = 100;

      // sort sections by their relative distance to the center of the window
      sectionArray.sort( function(a, b) { 
        return getDiff(a, window_scroll_top, window_center) > getDiff(b, window_scroll_top, window_center) ? 1 : -1; 
      });

      $(".section h1:visible").hide();
      $(sectionArray[0]).children("h1").show();

      $(".active").removeClass("active");
      $(sectionArray[0]).addClass("active");

    }

    // ----------------------------------------
    function getDiff(item, window_scroll_top, window_center) {
      var item_viewportoffset_top = $(item).offset().top - window_scroll_top;

      var dist_of_top = Math.abs(item_viewportoffset_top - window_center);
      var dist_of_bottom = Math.abs(item_viewportoffset_top + $(item).height() - window_center);

      // return minimum of distances of top and bottom of an element
      // to center of the window
      return Math.min( dist_of_top, dist_of_bottom );
    }
```

Comment: Works fine here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/98jxf6tg/) i made. make sure you are adding jQuery library.This function does the adding active class for you `display_section_titles()` and the display block is already in the css.

Comment: Thank you so much. You were correct, I forgot the JQuery library, that's relived hours of anguish